# New field in django-admin Add User

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using Django 1.7.1 and here I encountered issue that shouldn`t really took place.

Background: I'm working on customized user model based on AbstractUser. For now - I've got there one additional field (for testing) and planning to add more. Somehow I managed to making it work with DjangoAdmin using UserChangeForm with Meta class.

Problem: According to Django-docs there is no need to do anything more to get possibility to see, edit and add value to every field in my DjangoAdmin site. Unfortunately - Seeing and editing is working as expected but when it comes to "Add new User" by DjangoAdmin - I still see only three fields: "Username", "Password" and "Password confirmation".

Question: Where should I edit/put some code to get possibility to fill more fields while I`m creating new user by DjangoAdmin?

Ending: Yes - I've tried a lot of google results (including using 'fieldsets', 'list_display', 'inline' methods, etc.. As much, as possible - I would like also to avoid using OneToOne relation with User model. That generated so many mistakes that I gave up on it and I don't want to be back there. If there is such a need - I'll provide code snippets.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: The docs give a very in-depth example of a custom user model, including a custom `UserCreationForm` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Comment: I reffered to django-docs, so if it wasn`t clear enough - I've tried these solutions as well. It seems like problem here is with line:  add_form = UserCreationForm . It seems like there is no effects of this and I can't find out why. Secondly: using AbstractBaseUser instead of AbstractUser generates whole new set of errors.

Comment: Well your question has been answered then, that is where it's done. If you are running into problems with the way you implemented it, there's really nothing that can be done without seeing your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if the problem was with specific lines order in NewUserAdmin class or something else - haven`t tested it yet, but I'm pretty sure I was close to this solution much earlier. However this is the exact thing I was talking about (it is working the way I wanted it to :) ). I can now easy add any field to user model and it is still connected to all framework functions like sessions management, and so on. What is more - I don't use AbstractBaseUser nor OneToOne field, which caused a lot of problems. Anyway - thanks for any way of help. I wouldn't resolve it without you... ...this week :D

PS I skipped all imports. IDE will tell you, what is needed.

models.py

```
class NewUserManager(UserManager):
def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
    return UserManager.create_user(self, username, email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)

def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
    return UserManager.create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields)

class NewUser(AbstractUser):
    newField = models.CharField()       # for example CharField
    newField = models.CharField(max_length = 12) # important thing - properties should be in the second line
    objects = NewUserManager()

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'your_app_name.NewUser'
        #db_table = 'auth_user'
```

forms.py

```
class NewUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'newField')       # few example fields and new one: newField

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(NewUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class NewUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = NewUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'newField', 'last_login', 'is_staff')     # few example fields and new one: newField
```

admin.py

```
class NewUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = NewUserChangeForm
    add_form = NewUserCreationForm

    list_display = ('username', 'newField', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'last_login',)       # few example fields and new one: newField
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'newField', 'last_login', 'is_staff')}), # few example fields and new one: newField
)

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
        'classes': ('wide',),
        'fields': ('username', 'newField', 'password1', 'password2')}   # here are fields you want to have in django-admin AddUser view
    ),           # one of the most important place above
)

admin.site.register(NewUser, NewUserAdmin)
```